# Using ''fancyhdr'' to make headings - doesn't do this for first page of the section

Tags: header-footer

I am trying to use the `fancyhdr` package to make a header on **every page** of my document,

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
...
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{Some Text}
\fancyfoot[CO]{\thepage}
```

This almost works - every page has a header **except** the first page of every chapter/section. Is there a command to allow for headers on the first page of every section?

Comment: Do you want specific header for each page that includes the beginning of a new section?

Comment: See \fancypagestyle{plain{...} on pages 7=8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\chapter` of the class `book` contains an instruction `\thispagestyle{plain}`. Therefore, the easiest way to have the same heading on all the pages is to redefine the pagestyle `plain` with the command `\fancypagestyle`. This is explained p. 7 of the document `fancyhdr.pdf` which is the manual of `fancyhdr`.